# Why does saving a big Shapefile take so long?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, saga

When trying to save a large (281250 shapes), yet fairly simple shapefile (all shapes are rectangles with 5 attributes) from QGIS, it was still trying to save for over 2 to 3 hours before I killed it.  I tried multiple times over a full day. The same shapefile saves in approximately 10 seconds from SAGA GIS. So I did most of my table editing in SAGA. However, the string editing capabilities in SAGA are a bit lacking, so I brought the file back over to QGIS.  The edits to the strings using the Field Calculator were quick enough, but when I try and end the edit session and save the file, QGIS chokes really badly.

Am I doing something wrong, or does QGIS not handle shapefiles very well?

Comment: That is abnormal. I would try to save a copy with Save as... into different disk drives, perhaps that gives some info.

Comment: Where are you saving it? If it's on say a network drive, USB you may see slower performance depending on the connection speed

Comment: Are you hitting the 2 GB limit for shapefiles?

Comment: Shapefile is 37.4 MB, dbf is 18.4 MB.  So no, I am not hitting the 2 GB limit.   
Same results on network drive or local drive.  

The strange thing is that I can complete the same modification to the next to last column and save the file.  Takes approx 10 minutes which is *way* longer than SAGA GIS, but at least it completes.  However, when I complete the same modification to the last column, then the save process never completes.  Is there something 'special' about the last column of a shapefile dbf and the way that QGIS handles them that is causing this problem?

Comment: Another thing, why when I delete a column does QGIS have to go through loading **all** 281250 features in the attribute table?  This took well over 10 minutes to complete!  Then when I go to save the file, QGIS has to reload **all** 281250 features in the attribute table **again!**  Deleting this same column in SAGA GIS takes a second or less, then saving the results takes approx 10 seconds. If I delete two columns in QGIS, QGIS has to reload **all** 281250 features to the attribute table 2 times, before I even save!

Comment: Also, why does QGIS need to load **all** 281250 features to the attribute table just to view the attribute table?  Obviously, I can't look at the attributes of **all** 281250 features at once.  Can't QGIS simply display the column headers and load the first 100 rows,  then if I scroll past the 100 rows or resort the data, the dbf file will be re-queried to only display the rows that should then be displayed (with some extra above and below for smooth scrolling)?

Comment: Can you try the same without loading any plugins on QGIS startup? Especially the Digitizing plugins tend to slow down saving of layers.

Comment: Did you try Save as...? Can you share your data or create some artificial test data? Things work all too slow for you and there must be a reason for that somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Old question.... but I had same issue in QGIS 3 with almost one million points in a shape file. Saving as Geopackage instead solved the problem - saving took like 30 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

*"Another thing, why when I delete a column does QGIS have to go through loading all 281250 features in the attribute table? This took well over 10 minutes to complete! Then when I go to save the file, QGIS has to reload all 281250 features in the attribute table again!"*

QGIS does **not have to load any features** to delete columns or save the file. There are a couple of methods which can avoid this (using the GUI):

---

- Layer Properties > Fields

  You can toggle the editing of the shapefile (clicking the pencil icon), add/delete columns and access the field calculator:

  [image: Field Properties]

  Once edited, toggle the editing icon again and you will be prompted to either save or discard the edits.

---

- Processing Toolbox > QGIS geoalgorithms > Vector table tools > Delete column

  Here you can access a tool which allows you to delete a column and save it as a temporary shapefile (so you can edit it further before writing it to disk) or save it immediately as a shapefile.

---

Although this is not a direct answer to your problem, both methods above allows you to avoid loading the attribute table which could save you some time.